# Excel RTD - stops updating when user is typing into another Worksheet. Is there a workaround?

Tags: excel, rtd

We have a user using Excel 2019 (64 bit) RTD to stream market data into his Excel worksheet.

When he types into a different Worksheet (totally separate Excel Window), the market data stops updating into the other Worksheet until he is done typing.

From what I understand, Excel uses the same UI thread to interact with the user as it does to visually update the Worksheet with new values from RTD.  So it's logical that RTD updates pause while user is editing in Excel.

Is there is some way to open other Worksheets into a totally separate Excel instance that does not share the same UI thread with the instance running RTD?  Or is there some other workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way to force Excel to start a separate instance is to enter:

```
excel.exe /x
```

in the Windows search box.

There are a other methods as well, see:

[7 Ways to Open Multiple Instances of Excel](https://gorilla.bi/excel/open-multiple-instances-excel/#run-window)