# Excel RTD: running multiple instances, how to include formulas from the other workbook instance

Tags: excel-formula, rtd

We have a user who is running 2 separate workbooks which need to share data:

- *Pricing* workbook which has RTD to receive updated market data
- *Order Placement* workbook which uses RTD to place orders and receive status updates

Because of limitations in the RTD threading model, the user needs to run each workbook in a *separate* Excel instance. (See [Excel RTD - stops updating when user is typing into another Worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70672897/376527)).  The separate instances are started using `excel.exe /x`.

The user also wants to incorporate calculations from the *Pricing* Workbook into the *Order Placement* workbook.  When Excel is *not* running as separate instances, he can enter a simple formula into the *Order Placement* workbook by pressing "=" and then clicking on a cell in the *Pricing* workbook. The cell then gets updated with something like `[Pricing.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1`.

When Excel is running as separate instances, however, this doesn't work.

Is there another way to get the dynamically updating cell values from one workbook to the other?

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround:
Let the end user manually make the link by typing the reference.

you can make a reference generator to ease them into it. All they have to do is copy the result value, enter "=" and paste the result value:

```
="["&B3&"]"&C3&"!"&D3
```

[image: Example Reference generator]

Comment: I tried this, and while it does populate the _initial_ value from the Pricing.xslx workbook, I don't see that the formula updates when the value in Pricing.xlsx changes.  To replicate: open the 2 workbooks as _separate instances_, enter the link.  You will see the value.  Then change the value in the Pricing workbook.  The value in the linked workbook does not change.